# Why does it show segmentation error when i use geeksforgeeks online compiler? Is it due to my machine or error in online compiler

Tags: segmentation-fault, cp

I was typing my code in online code editor of geeksforgeeks and while compiling I got a segmentation errors!Is it due to my memory or the online compiler!

Comment: You need to include your code in order for someone to help you.

Comment: Actually I forgot to take the screenshot! But I just wanted to know is the error caused due to my machine or the compiler